# How to model data with unequal size of dependent and independent variables?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, mathematical-statistics, prediction, model

I have a machine process which takes 6 steps to produce a product. Steps 1 -5 are the machine doing some preparation inside the machine, no real production here.

Step 6 is the real production step that the machine does something to the product, but the product quality is related to preparation steps 1-5. There are many sensors (generating data in milliseconds) in the machine measuring a lot of parameters, at different steps the parameter value reading are very different.

I want to model the process parameters with product quality data but obviously the dependent variables (product quality) and independent variables (process data) has different size of observations. For example: at the end of the process (one production cycle), I may have 100 products(this number varies depending on whether the process is smooth or not), I don't know how to align these 100 lines of dependent variables with those independent variables (generated milliseconds) from those Steps 1-6, because for those 100 lines of dependent data, I could have >1000 lines of independent data. Any suggestion or solution?

Comment: Have you identified which measurements belong to which product (e.g. by time), or is that part of the question?

Comment: Hi, judo, thanks for your response. Ya, it is part of the question, there is some period of time during which product stays in the machine, say for 5 mins, but during this 5-min period of time, there are at least >50 lines of process data generated, I don't know how to match these lines of process data with just one line of product quality inspection data.

Comment: And the complicated thing is that even though only Step 6 is the real production step but those Step 1-5 machine preparation data are super important for the product quality, so including those process variable readings from step 1-5, I may have >100 lines of process data lines to match with only 1 product quality inspection data line. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your steps 1-5 generate time profiles that you then want to relate to the response which is like functional data. You may want to read the literature on design and modeling of dynamic experiments, e.g.Fiordalis, Andrew, and Christos Georgakis. "Data-driven, using design of dynamic experiments, versus model-driven optimization of batch crystallization processes." Journal of Process Control 23.2 (2013): 179-188.